# Centos Curl Http Error:404 Page does Not Exists

Tags: curl, centos

I have a webpage at http://example.com/route/function which is hosted on CentOS

This opens properly from the browser.

However, when I try to open this from centos curl command:

```
$curl -L http://example.com/route/function
```

I get the error

```
<h4> Http Error:404 Page does Not Exists ! </h4>
```

But if i just curl only the domain name, i get the response correctly.

```
$curl -L http://example.com/
```

The .htaccess has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a missing header or something. which header in particular is anyone's guess. could be a `User-Agent` block for all we know. anyway, start with this:

```
curl -v 'http://127.0.0.1/route/function' --location --cookie "" --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,nb;q=0.7' --compressed
```

it makes a very browser-like request (google chrome on windows 7 SP1 x64, to be specific), the webserver should not be able to notice that it's actually talking to curl, rather than a web browser. then remove the arguments 1 by 1, until it stops working. then congrats, the last argument you removed was probably the 1 that was required.

i have lots of experience with this stuff, and in my experience, it's usually the `Accept` string (where you get bogus if you `Accept: */*` (curl default) but you get what you want if you `Accept: text/html`), or the `User-Agent` string (where curl/wget is blacklisted), or the `Accept-Encoding` string (where you get bogus if you do *not* send `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` ) - but it could be any of them.